# Exposing a ECS instance hosted in private subnet to external world(public ip)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, nlb

I am having two .net core Web API's hosted in 2 docker containers Ex:- API1 on container C1 and API2 on C2 both listens to port 80. I have an ECS Cluster created inside a private subnet and I have hosted container C1 as a service inside the cluster.I  created an NLB inside the same private subnet which hooks to the cluster. In order to expose the API to the outside world, I created an API Gateway and connected with the NLB using VPC link.

I am able to access the API hosted in C1 perfectly well from the API gateway. Now I need to host C2 in the same ECS Cluster.H ow these 2 container instances coexist. How can I route between these two applications by creating two API Gateway's

I want to get clarity on

1. NLB capable of routing traffic to multiple Containers (API1 and API2)? Or will it provide dynamic host port mapping?
2. Do I need to switch to  ALB to achieve this?